# How should I mix validated and unvalidated properties for a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, properties, vue.js, vue-component

I have a VueJS component that has a validated property called "name"; however, the remaining properties will not be validated.

How should I reference my unvalidated properties? Should I simply insert an empty string or object (as I have done so below) as the property's value?

**The properties in my Vue component**

```
props: {
   name: { required: true },
   generatecontrchart: {}
}
```

Comment: You can indicate the property's type when there is no validation needed (ex: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question on the official VueJS forum and based off the answer there, you should do the following when you want to mix validated and unvalidated properties for a Vue component:

**You should set the unvalidated property to type:null, which means that it can be anything.**

```
props:{
  name:{type:String, required:true},
  generatecontrchart:{type:null}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `{type: null}` but you could simply define your property as `generatecontrchart: null`.